# How to get Golden Trove Carafe 2015

Tags: dota-2

I have purchased 5 Lockless Luckvase 2015 and 1 trove carafe but did not get any rare courier or golden trove carafe so is there any way to get these change or it just a cheap way to spent money as one of my friend opened 60 but did not get any rare but i have read one line while opening case that if i will add signature and if there will be 10 then there is chance to get rare so what is that? Golden trove carafe or anything else?

Second, how some people can sell these Golden trove carafe or items which are tradeable and marketable after few months? I have seen people selling golden trove carafe 2015 in 300+$ but if i try to sell my items then it says you can't sell items beofre nov 2015 then how can they?

Hope i will get good reply so i can save my self spending a lot money. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Golden Trove Carafe are a really rare drop when you open the new TI5 chests. Some people will get one with one purchase, other haven't seen one after 100 chests opening.

Unless Valve decides to link some of TI5 marchandise to a digitally unlockable Golden Trove Carafe, there are no other way than random drop to get one without going on the community market.

Items you get from the chest are not tradable/marketable for now however the Golden Trove Carafe itself is tradable/marketable. So the lucky owners of Golden Trove Carafe can already sell them on the market.

Comment: wow..i don't know about that fact that golden trove carafe is marketable. but what you mean by this line "Valve decides to link some of TI5 marchandise to a digitally unlockable Golden Trove Carafe". Sorry for asking much.

Comment: Golden Carafe are marketable for the same reason that the faceless rex courier is. For the marchandise : Valve has a real life secret shop and an online shop where you can buy stuff (shirt, mug, plushies, demi-heroes etc.). This stuff most of the time come with a digital unlock (which means a DotA2 in-game item that you unlock with a code). This unlock could be a Golden Carafe if Valve decides so

Comment: ohh..i even tried to buy a mug from secret shop but it says you need code and i did not get that code..:( i bought atleast 150$ items on dota2 but no any special code..:( but thanx for info.. :)

Answer (score -2):

You have a chance of receiving a golden trove carafe from a regular trove.

While I can not provide the actual odds, I can confirm receiving a golden trove carafe after 10 troves!

Comment: ohh that's great but i don't think this is what i wanted. This should be comment.